# -How to get the currency rate from the web service-

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Hiyee,I was trying to use the web service for currency rate to get the rate, althought I have already add web reference to["http://www.webservicex.net/CurrencyConvertor.asmx"] but I still do not know how to retrieve it from there. I'm using asp.net vb. 
Thanks!...

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Visual Studio then you can simply right-click your project and choose "add service reference" to your project specifying "http://www.webservicex.net/CurrencyConvertor.asmx" as address and then add code like this

```
  Dim client = New CurrencyConvertorSoapClient()
  Dim result = client.ConversionRate(Currency.EUR, Currency.USD)
  Console.WriteLine(result)
```

Comment: oh, but where to put those code? Sorry for asking this question, quite new with this.

Comment: in the place where you need the conversion rate, I'm not sure where it is in your project

Comment: oh, but there's error. The currencyconvertorysoapcliekt is not declare...Is it I missed out something?

Comment: I think you are missing the namespace import like
Imports MyProject.CurrencyConvertorService